# For loop with multiple conditions in r returning same values

Tags: r, for-loop, multiple-conditions

I have created some vector with logical values true and false, and I want to use a for loop to identify all the ones with "TRUE" value.

"Master", "master" and "MSc" are all 1:45 vectors, I want to use multiple "or" conditions to define that for all the "TRUE" values, a new vector will be created taking the value of "Master":

```
 n <- nrow(fs)
 for (i in 1:n) {
   if(Master[i]=="TRUE"||master[i]=="TRUE"||MSc[i]=="TRUE"){
     fs$data.linkedin_education_degree1[i] <- "Master"
   }
 }
```

While "Master", "master" and "MSc" look like:

```
> Master
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[24] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> master
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[24] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> MSc
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[24] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

After running this loop, I suppose I would get a few "Master" and "NA"s, but actually all the returned values are "Master"?!

```
> fs$data.linkedin_education_degree1
 [1] "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master"
[16] "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master"
[31] "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master" "Master"
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong in the loop. Can anybody offer some help? Many thanks!

---

edit by Paul Hiemstra:

The following example code does not reproduce your issue. Can you make the question reproducible, either by reproducing the issue using my example code or by providing the data for your code above:

```
m1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
m2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
m3 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
result = rep(NA, 3)

n <- length(m1)
for (i in 1:n) {
  if (m1[i] == 'TRUE' || m2[i] == 'TRUE') {
    result[i] = 'Master'
  }
}
# > result
# [1] "Master" "Master" NA
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a loop here.

Comment: Place them in a `list` and use `Reduce` i.e. `c(NA, "Master")[Reduce('|', list(Master, master, MSc)) + 1]`.  Also, if you have a logical vector, there is no need for `=="TRUE"`

Comment: What is the value of `fs$data.linkedin_education_degree1` when the condition `Master[i]=="TRUE"||master[i]=="TRUE"||MSc[i]=="TRUE"` is not met ?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, with some example data I constructed I could not reproduce your issue (I edited my example in your question, can you reproduce the issue with that data?). In addition, there is no need for the loop here, a vectorized approach will work better (faster, shorter code), e.g.: `ifelse(m1 | m2 | m3, 'Master', NA)`.

Comment: @Hugo I suppose it will be 'NA'?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes this works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided does not reproduce the problem your facing...

Anyway, as @Paul Hiemstra suggested in the comment you can do it without a loop, like this:

```
fs$data.linkedin_education_degree1 <- ifelse(Master | master | Msc, 'Master', NA)
```